# leer imagen MIME

Tags: python, api, mime

Estoy tratando de leer un jpg de una respuesta MIME que recibo mediante GET en python.
Pero no consigo que la imagen se lea correctamente ni encuentro ninguna libreria para tratar este tipo de mensajes. ¿alguna idea?.
La respuesta es de este modo:

```
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type:application/xml;charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length:132

<CaptureData version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
<captureProgress>100</captureProgress>
</CaptureData>

--MIME_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="ImageData";filename="ImageData.jpg"
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Content-Length:54578

IPKH.............
.............

--MIME_boundary--
```

Comment: *ni encuentro ninguna libreria para tratar este tipo de mensajes* Si de verdad hubieras buscado, hubieras encontrado que existe una librería en la biblioteca estandar: https://www.google.com/search?q=leer+mensajes+mime+python&rlz=1C1CHBD_esAR911AR911&oq=leer+mensajes+mime+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i546l2.4084j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. Por cierto, el mime que pusiste no parece ser valido.

Comment: Te respondería, pero como no demuestras que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda (puedes demostrarlo por ejemplo con una lista de algunos de los links que visitaste). Sin eso, tu pregunta parece del tipo "haganme la tarea".

Comment: Esa librería ya le he probado y no vale, puesto que no es un mail, si no un mensaje con estilo MIME.  También he probado esta https://pypi.org/project/mime/ y no saca correctamente la imagen.

Comment: Entonces, recibes una cadena con un mensaje MIME en forma de cadena a travez de un get?

Comment: Realmente es un post, puesto que tengo que mandar un xml de configuracion, pero si, es como dices.  Recibo ese mensaje tal cual, no he pegado el binario del jpg, pero ese es el mensaje completo tal cual lo recibo

Comment: Entonces, por que no te serviría [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) que tiene herramientas para parsear mails a partir de bytes y cadenas?

Comment: solo me saca la primera parte, captureprogress, pero la imagen no la lee. igual estoy haciendo algo mal, voy a darle una vuelta mas.

Comment: No se la causa. Pero espero que lo puedas o alguien pueda solucionarlo. Suerte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, el problema consistía en que el xml/mime no era estándar y por eso no funcionaba ninguna de las librerías. La solución fue tratarlo como texto y formatearlo para que cumpliera el estándar. Una vez hecho esto pude utilizar las librerías y sacar la información sin problema.